# Flutter transition from body to appbar on scroll

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How would you make a transition in a view where you have a title and, on scroll down, the title goes to the AppBar? When scrolling up again, it should behave otherwise.

This is an example of what I am trying to implement:

[Scroll Animation](https://youtube.com/shorts/mPwV6-5DGbs)

Answer (score 1):

You should use SliverAppBar this is an example for it [sliver_app_bar_example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html)